# The derivative of an empty function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let's say we have function with empty domain $f:\ \varnothing \rightarrow Y$.

Is this theoretically correct to say that the derivative of this function is another function with empty domain e.g. $g:\ \varnothing \rightarrow Y$?

(I know it's pointless to calculate a derivative of an empty function, but I want to know whether it is formally wrong to say so and if it contradicts with the definition of the deriviative)

Comment: The derivative isn't even defined in a general set theoretic context.

Comment: @lulu sorry I added that tag by mistake. I am asking in the context of (real) analysis.

Comment: Are you assuming $Y$ to be a subset of the real numbers?

Comment: @Servaes yes, but does this really matter? The set of values will be empty anyway.

Comment: You're right that the derivative has empty domain. But "another" can be confusing, since all functions with domain $\varnothing$ are equal, i.e., they're the same set of ordered pairs.

Comment: @MartinYakuza For the $\varepsilon,\delta$-definition of the derivative the codomain needs some distance function.

Answer (score 0):

From definition of a derivative we get that the function must be defined at the point under consideration. The defining equation is
$$\ f'(x)= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ for sufficiently small h. So here $\ f(x)$ $ \left[ also \ f(x+h)\right]$ has to be defined at some point in the domain. If the domain doesn't contain any point, then this defining equation doesn't make any sense as the functon $\ f(x)$ is not defined at any point. So there is no point in even considering the derivative where the main function is itself not defined.

Comment: I know that this is "pointless", but would it be wrong to say so? That the derivative is an empty function.

Comment: Obviously wrong.. because where the function itself doesn't exist, how can you differentiate that function?

Comment: it exist, it's just empty.

Comment: @MartinYakuza what is an empty function? A set can be empty. How can a function be empty?

Comment: function is a set

Comment: @MartinYakuza All I know is that a function is a correspondence between its domain and range set. To verify it, you may check [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics). A function acts like a bridge that sends an element from its domain to an element of its codmain.

Comment: function is a special case of a relation, and relation is a subset of cartesian product of two sets (usually called domain and codomain).

Comment: You are quoting "school" definition of function